# Error while running spark client mode on mesos using docker

Tags: apache-spark, client, mesos

we have a 3 node Mesos cluster. Master service was started on machine 1 using below command:

> sudo ./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=machine1-ip --work_dir=/home/mapr/mesos/mesos-1.7.0/build/workDir --zk=zk://machine1-ip:2181/mesos --quorum=1

and agent services on other 2 machines using below command:

> sudo ./bin/mesos-agent.sh --containerizers=docker --master=zk://machine1-ip:2181/mesos --work_dir=/home/mapr/mesos/mesos-1.7.0/build/workDir --ip=machine2-ip  --no-systemd_enable_support
>
> sudo ./bin/mesos-agent.sh --containerizers=docker --master=zk://machine1-ip:2181/mesos --work_dir=/home/mapr/mesos/mesos-1.7.0/build/workDir --ip=machine3-ip  --no-systemd_enable_support

Below property was set in machine1:

> export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so

we are trying to run spark job using docker image.
Note that we did not set "SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI" in machine1 because as per our understanding executor is going to run inside docker container and not on slave machine and hence this property is not required.

command used for spark submit is below(from machine 1):

> /home/mapr/newSpark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
>       --master mesos://machine1:5050 \
>       --deploy-mode client \
>       --class com.learning.spark.WordCount \
>       --conf spark.mesos.executor.docker.image=mesosphere/spark:2.4.0-2.2.1-3-hadoop-2.7 \
>       /home/mapr/mesos/wordcount.jar hdfs://machine2:8020/hdfslocation/input.txt hdfs://machine2:8020/hdfslocation/output

we are getting below error on spark submit:

Mesos task log:

> **I1211 20:27:55.040856  5996 exec.cpp:162] Version: 1.7.0
>   I1211 20:27:55.064775  6016 exec.cpp:236] Executor registered on agent 44c2e848-cd06-4546-b0e9-15537084df1b-S1
>   I1211 20:27:55.068828  6018 executor.cpp:130] Registered docker executor on company-i0058.company.co.in
>   I1211 20:27:55.069756  6016 executor.cpp:186] Starting task 3
>   /bin/sh: 1: /home/mapr/newSpark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/./bin/spark-class: not found
>   I1211 20:27:57.669881  6017 executor.cpp:736] Container exited with status 127
>   I1211 20:27:58.672829  6019 process.cpp:926] Stopped the socket accept loop**

messages on the terminal:

> **2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Running Spark version 2.4.0
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Submitted application: WordCount
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: mapr
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: mapr
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(mapr); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(mapr); groups with modify permissions: Set()
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 48069.
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SparkEnv:54 - Registering MapOutputTracker
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SparkEnv:54 - Registering BlockManagerMaster
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  DiskBlockManager:54 - Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-3a4afff7-b050-45ba-bb50-c9f4ec5cc031
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  SparkEnv:54 - Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
>   2018-12-11 20:27:49 INFO  log:192 - Logging initialized @3157ms
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  Server:351 - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT, build timestamp: unknown, git hash: unknown
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  Server:419 - Started @3273ms
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  AbstractConnector:278 - Started ServerConnector@1cfd1875{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6f0628de{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2b27cc70{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6f6a7463{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@79f227a9{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6ca320ab{/stages,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@50d68830{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e53135d{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6754ef00{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@619bd14c{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@323e8306{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@a23a01d{/storage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4acf72b6{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7561db12{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3301500b{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@24b52d3e{/environment,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@15deb1dc{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6e9c413e{/executors,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@57a4d5ee{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5af5def9{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a45c42a{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@36dce7ed{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b770e40{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@78e16155{/api,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@19868320{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@50b0bc4c{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  SparkUI:54 - Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://machine1:4040
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Added JAR file:/home/mapr/mesos/wordcount.jar at spark://machine1:48069/jars/wordcount.jar with timestamp 1544540270193
>   I1211 20:27:50.557170  7462 sched.cpp:232] Version: 1.7.0
>   I1211 20:27:50.560644  7454 sched.cpp:336] New master detected at master@machine1:5050
>   I1211 20:27:50.561132  7454 sched.cpp:356] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
>   I1211 20:27:50.571651  7456 sched.cpp:744] Framework registered with 5260e4c8-de1c-4772-b5a7-340480594ef4-0000
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 56351.
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  NettyBlockTransferService:54 - Server created on machine1:56351
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  BlockManager:54 - Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, impetus-i0053.impetus.co.in, 56351, None)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Registering block manager machine1:56351 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, impetus-i0053.impetus.co.in, 56351, None)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, machine1, 56351, None)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  BlockManager:54 - Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, machine1, 56351, None)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@73ba6fe6{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>   2018-12-11 20:27:50 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
>   2018-12-11 20:27:51 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 0 is now TASK_STARTING
>   2018-12-11 20:27:51 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 1 is now TASK_STARTING
>   2018-12-11 20:27:51 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 288.1 KB, free 366.0 MB)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:51 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 25.1 KB, free 366.0 MB)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:51 INFO  BlockManagerInfo:54 - Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on machine1:56351 (size: 25.1 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:51 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Created broadcast 0 from textFile at WordCount.scala:22
>   2018-12-11 20:27:52 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   2018-12-11 20:27:52 INFO  FileInputFormat:249 - Total input paths to process : 1
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  deprecation:1173 - mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  HadoopMapRedCommitProtocol:54 - Using output committer class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  FileOutputCommitter:108 - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Starting job: runJob at SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Registering RDD 3 (map at WordCount.scala:24)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Got job 0 (runJob at SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78) with 2 output partitions
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Final stage: ResultStage 1 (runJob at SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Submitting ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at WordCount.scala:24), which has no missing parents
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 1 is now TASK_RUNNING
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.0 KB, free 366.0 MB)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.9 KB, free 366.0 MB)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  BlockManagerInfo:54 - Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on machine1:56351 (size: 2.9 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1161
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Submitting 2 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at WordCount.scala:24) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1))
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  TaskSchedulerImpl:54 - Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
>   2018-12-11 20:27:53 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 0 is now TASK_RUNNING
>   2018-12-11 20:27:54 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 0 is now TASK_FAILED
>   2018-12-11 20:27:54 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 0 requested
>   2018-12-11 20:27:54 INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
>   2018-12-11 20:27:54 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
>   2018-12-11 20:27:54 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 1 is now TASK_FAILED
>   2018-12-11 20:27:54 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
>   2018-12-11 20:27:54 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 1 requested
>   2018-12-11 20:27:54 INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 1
>   2018-12-11 20:27:54 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 2 is now TASK_STARTING
>   2018-12-11 20:27:55 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 3 is now TASK_STARTING
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 2 is now TASK_RUNNING
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 2 is now TASK_FAILED
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Blacklisting Mesos slave b92da3e9-a9c4-422a-babe-c5fb0f33e027-S0 due to too many failures; is Spark installed on it?
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 2 requested
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 2
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 2 from BlockManagerMaster.
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 3 is now TASK_RUNNING
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Mesos task 3 is now TASK_FAILED
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend:54 - Blacklisting Mesos slave 44c2e848-cd06-4546-b0e9-15537084df1b-S1 due to too many failures; is Spark installed on it?
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 3 requested
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 3 from BlockManagerMaster.
>   2018-12-11 20:27:57 INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 3
>   2018-12-11 20:28:08 WARN  TaskSchedulerImpl:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources**